# Getting JSON file from WordPress through Cloud9 returns a Cloud9 html file

Tags: angularjs, json, wordpress, ionic-framework, cloud9-ide

I have been using Cloud9 to make an Ionic app.

So far, the frontend of the app is doing fine. I use the ionic-framework through Cloud9.

My backend is another Cloud9 project. It uses WordPress to make a specific custom post type with advanced custom fields. It then uses WP REST API to generate that data in a json format. I can access my custom post type and its fields when I run the WordPress on Cloud9 using its /wp-json/posts?type=[specific type].

The problem is, when using a $http.get request in my ionic app, it doesn't work at all. If I use $http.get on a json file I downloaded from my WordPress and added in the workspace of my ionic app, everything works fine.

So, I have a problem getting json data from a WordPress site hosted using Cloud9 through an ionic app, also in a Cloud9 workspace.

Both workspaces are separated and run at the same time.

My code to load the json file is the following :

```js
var defer = $q.defer();

$http.get('LINK TO .../wp-json/posts?type=[post type]', { cache: 'true'})
    .success(function(data) {
           defer.resolve(data);
    });

return defer.promise;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

As mentionned, when I replace the link with [name of json file].json, a file that was directly downloaded from the REST API generated json and so that is identical to the site I'm trying to get, it doesn't work.

When I console.log(data), instead of logging the data for each custom post (what happens with the download .json), it logs this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
        <!--C9LOCAL_CODE_INJECT_PLACEHOLDER-(login-head)-DO_NOT_REMOVE-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Sign-in | Cloud9 IDE - Ajax.org</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Meet Cloud9, development-as-a-service for Javascripters and other developers"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content=""/>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/homepage/favicon.ico" />

        <!--C9LOCAL_CODE_INJECT_PLACEHOLDER-(login-loadedDetectionScript)-DO_NOT_REMOVE-->
        <link href="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/oldclient/homepage/style/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/oldclient/homepage/js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // ClickTale Top part
            var WRInitTime=(new Date()).getTime();
            // ClickTale end of Top part
        </script>
        <div id="header">
            <a class="logo" href="/"></a>
            <div class="social">
                <div class="socialMediaBlok">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://c9.io/" data-text="Cloud9 IDE - Your code anywhere, anytime" data-count="horizontal" data-via="cloud9ide">Tweet</a>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
                </div>
                <div class="socialMediaBlok">
                    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=c9.io&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21"
                      allowtransparency="true"
                      scrolling="no"
                      frameborder="0"
                      style="border:none; overflow:hidden;height:20px"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headerdivider"></div>
        <div id="signin_window">
            <div id="signinViewport">
                <div class="pageContainer">
                    <div id="barForgetPass" class="page">
                        <form id="resetPasswordForm">
                            <div class="header">Reset password</div>
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <div id="lbl_inpResetPassword" class="c9-label">
                                    <label for="inpResetPassword">Username or email address</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="c9-textbox">
                                    <div class="c9-txt_fix">
                                        <input type="text" id="inpResetPassword" name="inpResetPassword" disabled2="disabled" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <div class="fbox">
                            <div id="btnRPCancel" class="cancel-button button">Go back</div>
                            <div id="btnRP" class="action-button button">Reset my password</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="label3">Your password will be reset and you will receive an email with a new password.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="barSignIn" class="page">
                        <form id="signinForm">
                            <div class="header">Please sign in</div>
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <div id="lbl_inpUsernameEmail" class="c9-label">
                                    <label for="inpUsernameEmail">Username or email address</label>
                                </div>
                                <div id="txt_inpUsernameEmail" class="c9-textbox">
                                    <div class="c9-txt_fix">
                                        <input type="text" id="inpUsernameEmail" name="inpUsernameEmail" tabindex="1" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="lbl_inpPassword" class="c9-label">
                                    <label for="inpPassword">Password</label>
                                    <a id="forgetlink" class="forgetlink">Forgot?</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="txt_inpPassword" class="c9-textbox">
                                    <div class="c9-txt_fix">
                                        <input type="password" id="inpPassword" name="inpPassword" tabindex="2" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="fbox">
                                    <div id="cbRememberLogin" class="c9-checkbox" tabindex="3">
                                        <div class="check"></div><span>Remember my login</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="btnSignIn" class="action-button button" tabindex="4"  accesskey="ENTER">Sign in</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="barSignInStatusMsg" class="signinstatus-bar">
                                <div id="lblSignInHeader" class="errorboxContent"></div>
                                <div id="lblSignInStatus" class="errorboxContent"></div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
<!--                        <div id="btnLoginViaGitHub" class="c9-button btn-github" style="margin: 13px 0 0 12px;" tabindex="5"></div>-->
                        <div class="signin_options">
                            <div class='info'>Or sign in with:</div>
<!--                            <a href="#" class="c9-button google-signin" tabindex="8"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="c9-button twitter-signin" tabindex="7"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="c9-button facebook-signin" tabindex="6"></a>-->
                            <a href="#" class="c9-button github-signin"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="c9-button bitbucket-signin"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="barActivationLink" class="page">
                            <form id="activationlinkForm">
                                <div class="header">Activation email</div>
                                <div class="form-holder">
                                    <div id="lbl_inpResetPassword" class="c9-label">
                                        <label for="inpResetPassword">Username or email address</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c9-textbox">
                                        <div class="c9-txt_fix">
                                            <input type="text" id="inpResendConfirmation" name="inpResendConfirmation" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            
                            <div class="fbox">
                                <div id="btnALCancel" class="cancel-button button">Go back</div>
                                <div id="btnAL" class="action-button button">Resend activation email</div>
                            </div>
                            <!--div style="clear: both"></div-->
                        <!--div class="divider" style="margin:40px 5px 0 5px;"></div>
                        <div class="label3" style="margin:21px 17px 0 17px;">To receive the registration email again please click the button above.</div-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="signup_window">
            <div class="no_account_yet"></div>
            <div class="signuplink-bar">
                <div class="bird"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    <a id="btnSignUpUrl" href="/signup">SIGN UP</a> FOR YOUR ACCOUNT
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--        <div id="terms_of_use">
            <a href="#">Terms of use</a> - &#169; 2011 - <a href="/">Register here</a>
        </div>-->
        <div class="sign_up_now">
            <a id="resendactivation">Resend my activation email</a>
        </div>
        

        <ul class="bottom_menu">
            <li><a href="/" class="selected">Home</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Talk to us at <a href="http://twitter.com/cloud9ide/" target="_blank">Twitter</a> and <a href="http://www.facebook.com/Cloud9IDE/" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
<!--            <li>|</li>-->
<!--            <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>-->
            <li>|</li>
            <li>Cloud9 IDE, Inc &#169; 2011</li>
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/oldclient/homepage/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/oldclient/homepage/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/oldclient/homepage/js/components.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/oldclient/homepage/js/code.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.c9.io/nc-3.1.2733-9ac8c40a/static/oldclient/homepage/js/signin.js"></script>
        <!-- ClickTale Bottom part -->
        <div id="ClickTaleDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript%20src=\"" + (document.location.protocol == "https:" 
                ? "https://clicktale.pantherssl.com/" 
                : "http://s.clicktale.net/") + "WRc5.js\"%20type=\"text/javascript\"%3E%3C/script%3E"));
            </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ClickTaleSSL = 1;
            if (typeof ClickTale == "function")
                ClickTale(48230, 1, "www");
        </script>
        <!-- ClickTale end of Bottom part -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, since I use chrome as a debugger for my app, I use an extension for Access-Control-Expose-Headers. Without this extension, I get another error for the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to allow services to make API calls to your app (or Wordpress) you'll need to open the Share menu in the top right and make your app public.

In this case, you can lock down your app with authentication in the API so the publicness of your app shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked !

I just realised it redirected me to Cloud9 login page. So yeah, all I had to do was make the WordPress workspace public (at least until I host it).